# Lebesgue integration by parts in Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $\phi, \psi \in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and we want to integrate by parts the following piece: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\psi'(x)dx$$
Supposedly, it should look like this: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(x)\psi'(x)dx = \phi(x)\psi(x)\bigg\rvert_{\mathbb{R}}-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi'(x)\psi(x)dx$$
The quastion is what exactly is the first item? Is it $\phi(x)\psi(x)\bigg\rvert_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$? But limits $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\phi(x), \lim_{x\to-\infty}\phi(x), \lim_{x\to+\infty}\psi(x), \lim_{x\to-\infty}\psi(x)$ in a usual sense may not exist. So how then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$C_c^\infty$, the space of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support is dense in $W^{1,2}$. Let $\{\phi_n\}$, $\{\psi_n\}$ be sequences in $C_c^\infty$ converging to $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively in $W^{1,2}$. We have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_n\,\psi'_n=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi'_n\,\psi_n.
$$
Taking limits as $n\to\infty$ we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi\,\psi'=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi'\,\psi.
$$
since $\phi_n\to\phi$, $\phi'_n\to\phi'$, $\psi_n\to\psi$ and $\psi'_n\to\psi'$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Do I understand right, that convergence of ${\phi_n}, {\psi_n}$ to $\phi, \psi$ is in sense of convergence in $W^{1,2}$, not in $L^2$? So we also have ${\phi_n'}, {\psi_n'}$ converging to $\phi', \psi'$? Btw, could you recommend some literature on this matter?

Comment: Yes, it is convergence in $W^{1,2}$. This is equivalent to  $\phi_n\to\phi$ and $\phi'_n\to\phi'$ in $L^2$.

Comment: Adam's Sobolev spaces is a classical. PDE books like the one by Evans also study Sobolev spaces.