# Integration by parts $H^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If I am considering the space of $H^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions, I have my functions must vanish at infinity by Morrey’s inequality (tell me if I am wrong). Then, we have also if u is real...

\begin{equation}
2\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} u \frac{du}{dx} = [u^2]^{\infty}_{-\infty} 
\end{equation}

Does the right-hand side equal zero or does it in some framework I am not considering?

Comment: By Sobolev embedding, $u\in C^1$, and it vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Would $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{du}{dx} v + \frac{dv}{dx} u dx = [uv]^{\infty}_{-\infty} = 0$ also?

Comment: depends on where $v$ lives

Comment: You also might like to see this, which only uses density: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257420/lebesgue-integration-by-parts-in-sobolev-space-w1-2-mathbbr

Comment: in $H^2$ as well!

Comment: thanks you so much! was a good suggestion